# Linking to a file in the Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

When I link directly to an uploaded file in a Zend Framework based project I get differing results depending on if I'm working in my local environment or my remote environment.

In both cases I want to link to an uploaded photo. The generated URL looks like:

http://whateverserverweareon/projectfiles/project18/photos/aphoto.jpg

On my local machine clicking that link will show me the photo, in my remote machine it gives me a warning about "invalid controller..." (as, while I do not have a "projectfiles" controller, the uploaded photos are in the projectfiles directory on the path specified in that sample url).

So how do I link to these uploaded photos? Create a controller just so I can link to them? Can I bypass the controller altogether and link directly? Is there some sort of custom route I need to create? Should I be doing this in a completely different manner? Any suggestions?

Comment: what do your rewrite rules look like on the server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception means that on remote mashine your file does not exists in specified location. Standard rewrite rules in .htaccess file is written so that if your file exists (i.e. /projectfiles/project18/photos/aphoto.jpg) then index.php file of ZF will not be executed. You should check that your file exists.

Answer (score 0):

ischenkodv is right.
And also, it's a better practice to put your file somewhere out of index.php's directory tree. Perhaps another subdomain.